# Reorder / Fill the missing numbers in a sequence using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I have a table "number" having a column "n" which is of type int. I inserted some values like,

```
n
--
1
3
5  
8  
10
```

Now I want to the column n as 1,2,3,4,5. That is 3 should be changed as 2, 5 as 3, 8 as 4 and 10 as 5. The values of column n should be reordered with the missing values. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @counter := 0;
UPDATE `number`
SET `number`.`n` = (@counter := @counter + 1)
ORDER BY `number`.`n` ASC;
```

While executing from code using connector which not support multi-statements, both statements are to be executed in the same connection.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that 3 is changed to 2, or 1 remains untouched.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Why? what's the reason? `ORDER BY` clause guarantee the processing order, is it?

Comment: You are quite right, I didn't know one could order by an update.

Comment: @Akina what if we have two tables to be reordered. Given link. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206558/reorder-fill-the-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-using-mysql-in-two-different-ta?noredirect=1&lq=1