# Reorder missing numbers in a sequencein two different tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

This is an extended question of [reorder/ fill missing value in a sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206452/reorder-fill-the-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-using-mysql)

I have a table "number" having a column "n" which is of type int. I inserted some values like,

```
n
--
1
3
5
9
11
```

i also have another table "num" having column "n" which is of type int. I inserted some values like,

```
n
--
7
12
15
23
```

Now I want the column n of "number" table as 1,2,3,5,6 and column n of "num" table as 4,7,8,9. That is 1 should be as 1, 3 as 2, 5 as 3, 7 from "num" table as 4 and 9 as 5 and so on. The values of column n should be reordered with the missing values on both the tables.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206452/reorder-fill-the-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-using-mysql). You should at least point back to previous questions of yours which are  similar to a current one. Take a look on how to ask questions [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: @Vérace Working on single table and two tables are different cases. This should have different logic

Comment: Why are there gaps in the desired series? I don't get the logic behind this. Please try and explain the rules of that series more specifically.

Comment: For my case, Table "num" has unprocessed data. Table "number" has processed data. If any rows removed from "number" table, they are moved to some other table. The values of "number" and "num" tables should be reordered.

Comment: I think the simplest way is: create temporary table, copy both `n`-s to it, fill another field with natural numbers ordered as `n`-s, and then update tables and replace old `n`-s with new one. The most problem may be duplicates in tables - You may desire what to to with it.

Comment: I solved the problem as @Akina helped. Please simplify if possible since  I am a learner

Answer (score 0):

```
drop procedure IF EXISTS ALTERTABLEVALUES;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ALTERTABLEVALUES()
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE total_count INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE val varchar(5);
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE table_num INT;
DECLARE table_tab varchar(5);
DECLARE number_cursor CURSOR FOR select num,tab from tempnumbers;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 0;

drop temporary table if exists tempnumbers;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempnumbers as
select num,'temp' as tab from numbers union select num,'audit' as tab from numbers1 order by num;
SET val = (select num from tempnumbers limit 1);
SET total_count = (select count(*) from tempnumbers);

OPEN number_cursor;
get_values: LOOP
FETCH number_cursor INTO table_num,table_tab;
IF finished = 0 THEN 
 LEAVE get_values;
 END IF;
IF table_tab = 'temp' THEN 
    update numbers set numbers.num = val where numbers.num = table_num;
ELSE
    update numbers1 set numbers1.num = val where numbers1.num = table_num;
END IF;
SET val = val +1;
END LOOP get_values;
CLOSE number_cursor;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempnumbers;
END;
$$
delimiter ;

After running the procedure I got numbers table as
n
--
1
2
3
5
6

and numbers1 table as 

n
--
4
7
8
9

This is how i expected for the result.
```